# ETH_P_IP is not working as expected, I can only receive incoming packets

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, packet

I'm trying to use Packet socket to get both incoming and outgoing IP packets.

When I create socket, I've specified `ETH_P_IP` parameter,

`socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP)`

But with `ETH_P_IP`, I can only see `incoming` packets, not outgoing ones. If I use `ETH_P_ALL`, I can see them all.

So, what's the "correct" flags to use?

Comment: Are you sure the outgoing packets you see with ETH_P_ALL are actually IP packets? There is one speciality, if you want to see packets not destined for your machine or not originating from your machine then you need to put the socket into promiscuous mode. But that probably doesn't relate to your problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with dev_add_pack.  Change it to ETH_P_ALL and you see inbound and outbound.  I'm trying to figure out *why* this is the behavior, though.  Why doesn't ETH_P_IP show outbound as well?

Comment: Apparently, this behavior is by design.  This message is from 1999, but it describes the behavior we're seeing: https://lkml.org/lkml/1999/12/23/112